# Exclude phrases from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Perhaps the phrasing of the question shows I'm far from knowledgeable in the finer details of php, but I have a query that I use that goes like this:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM project_data WHERE budget='200'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100";
    $database->setQuery( $query );
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
?><?php
foreach( $rows as $row ){?> 
    <?=$row->budget?> <?=$row->title?>
    <?=$row->description?>
<?php
}?>
```

I'd really like to eliminate results where the description contains certain phrases, like "cheap" or "lowest price".  Maybe the question is to far reaching but maybe someone can help.

Comment: So add another case to where: `WHERE description NOT LIKE "%cheap%"`

Comment: Yes, this works, I just added - AND description NOT LIKE '%cheap price%' - after the budget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AND description NOT LIKE "%lowest price%"
```

`%` means there can be any string.